# Changing periodicity of panel data in R

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, panel-data

I have this banking panel data which is in monthly frequency. I want to convert to a quarterly frequency using the mean of the three months in a given quarter. Below is the head() of my data frame:

```
    db %>% select(Data,Bank,PC) %>% head()
    # A tibble: 6 x 3
      Data       Bank                             PC
      <date>     <chr>                         <dbl>
    1 2017-01-01 BANCO BM&FBOVESPA        502630099.
    2 2017-01-01 BANCO BONSUCESSO S.A.   1716340938.
    3 2017-01-01 BANCO BRADESCARD        5334785523.
    4 2017-01-01 BANCO BTG PACTUAL S.A. 98935990703.
    5 2017-01-01 BANCO CBSS               596039238.
    6 2017-01-01 BANCO CIFRA              116806412.
```

This dataset contains monthly data for the year 2017 for more than 100 banks. I need to convert each bank series into a quarterly frequency. So in the example above, I need to compute the mean of PC for each quarter of the year for each bank in the sample. In other words, I need to change the frequency of my Panel data from monthly to quarterly. How can I accomplish data in R?

Below is a subset of my data if anyone wants to try it.

```
    structure(list(Data = structure(c(17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 
    17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501), class = "Date"), 
Bank = c("BANCO ORIGINAL", "BANCO ORIGINAL", "BANCO ORIGINAL", 
"BANCO ORIGINAL", "BANCO ORIGINAL", "BANCO ORIGINAL", "BANCO ORIGINAL", 
"BANCO ORIGINAL", "BANCO ORIGINAL", "BANCO ORIGINAL", "BANCO ORIGINAL", 
"BANCO ORIGINAL"), Taxonomy = c("BANCOS MULTIPLOS", "BANCOS MULTIPLOS", 
"BANCOS MULTIPLOS", "BANCOS MULTIPLOS", "BANCOS MULTIPLOS", 
"BANCOS MULTIPLOS", "BANCOS MULTIPLOS", "BANCOS MULTIPLOS", 
"BANCOS MULTIPLOS", "BANCOS MULTIPLOS", "BANCOS MULTIPLOS", 
"BANCOS MULTIPLOS"), Liq = c(1.1997748808169, 1.19259719096416, 
1.17984955128666, 1.18695199874656, 1.19834389025218, 1.22404552882798, 
1.24812868632381, 1.25155515564228, 1.23908341171122, 1.22923764062342, 
1.22573014109315, 1.19451856437255), Cap = c(0.0564130001266887, 
0.0511332310836733, 0.055115912263737, 0.0610766393321285, 
0.0516610760871821, 0.0519465686269887, 0.0582801135631064, 
0.053508898053011, 0.0557890616137837, 0.0639122025397535, 
0.0588865316259913, 0.0534625111456079), Size = c(24.3393816873135, 
24.4387493714898, 24.3615598295339, 24.2589048360285, 24.4251409240454, 
24.4154251928763, 24.3141208787945, 24.4120044047441, 24.3647597828241, 
24.219599367394, 24.304650218349, 24.3922876799839), risk = c(0.220292714085706, 
0.226351022665361, 0.225513481661864, 0.261226698162742, 
0.268547230949181, 0.193220911345295, 0.189681335841555, 
0.203642574652873, 0.17111480849187, 0.198715216005694, 0.189870257131344, 
0.13419221010663), profitability = c(-0.01753800950183, -0.0175186818010891, 
-0.017557013896287, -0.0175563818325023, -0.0175772644337278, 
-0.0176513268874473, -0.0161626726677722, -0.015962366730429, 
-0.0160506385110374, -0.0161994381957536, -0.0161484427069834, 
-0.0162943410707466)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: First you need to say how this is to be done. By bank? Mean of PC? Describe the logic to be applied. Also search on `[r] monthly quarterly`

Comment: I need to compute the mean for every variable in the database by bank. So in the example above, I need to compute the mean of PC for every quarter for each bank so I obtain a Panel data but with quarterly frequency.

Comment: So in a dditon to describing what yopu want to see, you now need to provide an example datast, preferably in a manner that can be easily incorporate into testing. Using `dput` or `dump` are the best ways for dataframes or tibbles.

Comment: I edited and provided a subset of my data. Is that sufficient? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the month value by three (and add one to shift `qtr` to 1:4). You may want to paste on a year value if the data spans multiple years:

```
 aggregate(dat[4:8], list( qtr=as.POSIXlt(dat$Data)$mon%/%3 +1, bank=dat$Bank), mean)
  qtr           bank      Liq        Cap     Size      risk profitability
1   1 BANCO ORIGINAL 1.190741 0.05422071 24.37990 0.2240524   -0.01753790
2   2 BANCO ORIGINAL 1.203114 0.05489476 24.36649 0.2409983   -0.01759499
3   3 BANCO ORIGINAL 1.246256 0.05585936 24.36363 0.1881462   -0.01605856
4   4 BANCO ORIGINAL 1.216495 0.05875375 24.30551 0.1742592   -0.01621407
```

Turns out there is a yearqtr class in zoo that would be even better:

```
library(zoo)
aggregate(dat[4:8], list( qtr=as.yearqtr(dat$Data), bank=dat$Bank), mean)
      qtr           bank      Liq        Cap     Size      risk profitability
1 2017 Q1 BANCO ORIGINAL 1.190741 0.05422071 24.37990 0.2240524   -0.01753790
2 2017 Q2 BANCO ORIGINAL 1.203114 0.05489476 24.36649 0.2409983   -0.01759499
3 2017 Q3 BANCO ORIGINAL 1.246256 0.05585936 24.36363 0.1881462   -0.01605856
4 2017 Q4 BANCO ORIGINAL 1.216495 0.05875375 24.30551 0.1742592   -0.01621407
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the library `lubridate` you can generate the quarter:

```
library(lubridate)
db %>% mutate(qData = quarter(Data))
```

Best!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your input but it's not that I'm looking for. The quarter() function gives me which quarter of the year the data belongs to. Or at least this is what I understood from the documentation. However, I need to change the frequency of my data. In the example above, I need to compute the mean of PC for every quarter for each bank, so I can obtain a Panel data with a quarterly frequency. Do you have any suggestions?